# What is the significance of numbered tiles on walls in Rome?

Tags: rome

Around Rome, I noticed many numbered tiles (most with four digits, and all with a white background and blue text) around the city. An example is shown below on the right of the image.

[image]

Some of these tiles were placed at the entrances of historically important buildings (for example, Santi Quatro Coronati has a numbered tile), but many were at addresses with no discernable importance. I also verified that the number on the tile did not correspond to the street number. (This is evident, for example, for the property in the picture above; the street number is 28).

What is the significance of locations with these tiles? Is there a system behind their numbering / a list of all the locations of the tiles? [More images are available in this album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWBTr.jpg).

Comment: I realize that this may not be the most appropriate site for this question (I considered posting it on Travel too); if there is a more appropriate site I'd appreciate knowing!

Comment: Indeed in travelexchange: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95009/what-do-the-additional-numbers-on-the-side-of-houses-in-rome-stand-for (but by the answer it is clear that the question is on-topic here).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's already answered on another SE, as another comment indicates ("Duplicate" closures are required to be on this SE).

Comment: @SJuan76 what search term did you use to find this? (or did you know about it before hand)

Comment: `number wall`. I did recall seeing some question about strange numbers, but I did not remember if it was specific to Rome.